# How can I become active in the Ubuntu Community

Tags: community

I have used Ubuntu for a while and want to find a way to give back to the community and help Ubuntu get better; is there a team in the Ubuntu community that is dedicated to helping users transition from user to contributer?

Comment: @cprofitt There might be some overlap with this question, so you might want to define a scope further: http://askubuntu.com/questions/692/how-can-i-contribute-to-ubuntu