# How do I give back to the Ubuntu community?

Tags: community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I contribute to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692/how-can-i-contribute-to-ubuntu)

I made a switch to Ubuntu about 3 years ago and I'm more than happy with it. As it is free, I feel it's not right unless I give back something to the community. What are the ways in which I could give back to the Ubuntu community?

Comment: Take  alook at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10573/how-can-i-become-active-in-the-ubuntu-community?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest and less time consuming method is to help in translations. Check out launchpad and help to translate your favorite projects in your language.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy a new computer think of a company called system 76 they  OEM Ubuntu Computers. https://www.system76.com/

You can also send them a self addressed stamped envelope and they will mail you Ubuntu stickers.

Help others learn about ubuntu and LibreOffice or OpenOffice