# How can I contribute to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: development, contributing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I contribute to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692/how-can-i-contribute-to-ubuntu)

I'm a noob, but I want to help, I want to be apart of Ubuntu. What can I do to learn, or help with the development of Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Also see the *Whole*  of the right panel of the Askubuntu.com site ----> Under related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First welcome to Ubuntu. Best you can do to contribute to development is to run 12.04 and file bug reports.

Test on as much hardware as you can, from Vritualbox to KVM to any hardware you can use.

See

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Other things to learn is other areas of communication.

Do you know how to use IRC ? If so, join #ubuntu+1

There is also discussion on the Ubuntu forums

http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=412