# What are some Ubuntu projects to contribute?

Tags: java, launchpad, c++, c, contributing

I decided to take part upon developing **Ubuntu** applications although I am having trouble finding projects to contribute in C, C++, C# and Java at Launchpad (not necessarily Launchpad alone). Can you offer several projects that are Ubuntu related?

Comment: related, not necessarily a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/692/how-can-i-contribute-to-ubuntu See the results under the 'contributing' tag for more suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [OpenHatch](https://openhatch.org/).

> OpenHatch is a non-profit organization with the goals of lowering the barriers to entry into the open source community and increasing diversity.

While not directly affiliated with Ubuntu or Canonical, OpenHatch has project listing of a number of upstream projects (Django, LibreOffice, Rhythmbox, for example) in a variety of languages and difficulty that have the potential to improve Ubuntu.

For the beginning developers, the site also has a number of basic tutorials ['missions'](https://openhatch.org/missions/) aimed at getting the budding developer familiar with using dev tools such at git, diff, and patch.

A [quick search on 'Ubuntu'](https://openhatch.org/search/?q=ubuntu) shows a number of projects available that directly relate to Ubuntu such as writing test cases or working on a bug in Evince.

Disclaimer: I've had the OpenHatch site linked in my user profile for some time, but I am no way affiliated with them other then being a member on their site. Hope this helps in getting you pointed in the right direction.