# Where or when can I ask Ubuntu employees questions related to Ubuntu?

Tags: community, irc, google-hangouts

- Where or when can I ask Ubuntu employees questions related to Ubuntu?
- Is there a Google Hangouts session where they regularly take questions from the community?
- Is there a Schedule for that hypothetical Google Hangouts session?
- Are there perhaps any IRC Channels where I can find them (To ask only legitimate questions of course, that won't waste their time)?
- Is there a youtube Channel where these hangouts are posted to that I can subscribe to, to see the google hangout sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's really no concept of "Ubuntu employees". Ubuntu is made by Ubuntu Developers, who may or may not be paid to work on Ubuntu, which can incorporate work from a variety of projects.

There are regular Ubuntu Developer Hangouts posted on:

- http://ubuntuonair.com/
- http://ubuntuonair.com/calendar/

As well as regular Hangout sessions as part of the Ubuntu Online Summit, which is posted here:

- http://uds.ubuntu.com/
- http://summit.ubuntu.com/ - the schedule is posted here, including links to sessions and their respective YouTube videos.

For IRC and other resources, check:

- http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/
- [How can I contribute to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692/how-can-i-contribute-to-ubuntu?rq=1)